# SQL statement that returns exactly one row with columns

Tags: postgresql

I'm having trouble creating a query for the following task: i want to return exactly one row with columns: region_id, region_name, province_name, province_code, country_name, country_code for any given regionid. The database has 3 tables "countrylist" , "provinces" and "regionlist"

the table countrylist has the following columns : countryid, language code, countryname, countrycode and continentid

provinces : country_code, country_name, province_code, province_name

regionlist: regionid, regiontype.

So I tried writing a query for joining the table but I'm sure if I'm doing it correct.

exactly one row with columns: region_id, region_name, province_name, province_code, country_name, country_code for any given regionid.

Comment: The statement would probably help to find out, what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% aware of the differences between Postgres and MySQL - but guess you get the idea at the very least.

One way to do it, to get your id with `WHERE regionlist.regionid =` and join the other tables. From either the regionlist you can use the `LIMIT` [(reference)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-limit.html) to get a limited amount of rows.

Apparently neither `provinces` nor `country` have a common column with `regionlist`, so I can not tell where the link between those are. However, once you have 1 row of the region list you should have no troubles joining them with the others (if the links are trivial).

Comment: With your current data model you cannot get what you desire. In order to get that you need to associate either country or provinces with either a column for region in the appropriate table (if 1:M) or a resolution table (if M:M) - this could also require additional data. With your current data model you get country+province combined with every region. While you can use the limit clause to restrict the number of rows that alone does not ensure the same row is returned on subsequent executions.